# Is there a more efficient (in terms of memory foot print) binding to datagrid other than datatable and dataview

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding, wpfdatagrid

Is there a more efficient (in terms of memory foot print) binding to datagrid other than datatable and dataview?

I have a datagrid bound to a dataview which seems to be guzzling a lot of memory . is there a leaner way of doing this?

Comment: See [does the wpf datagrid have a virtual mode like the winforms DataGridView?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/6982301/60761)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

And better yet than list is the ObservableCollection which will properly notify the GUI controls of changes in your list: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms668604.aspx

Comment: No an ObservableCollection does not inform the UI of changes IN the list.  An ObservableCollection informs the UI of inserts and deletes.   Via NotifyPropertyChanged on the item is how the UI is informed of changes in both a List or ObservableCollection.   The question is footprint and List is lighter than an ObservableCollection.

Answer (score 1):

A DataTable is a relatively heavy weight object.  It saves changes where you can revert or committ.  Supports sorting and filtering.  Build a light weight class with the public properties you need and pass them in the contructor.  Then put those objects in a List and bind to the List.   DataGrid is alsoo powerfull and not light.   If you just need simple read only then go with GridView ListView.   I have an app with million of records and present records them 40 at a time.   With ListView virtualiztion you can even present 1000s of rows.

Comment: And why did you take away my answer?  I answered the stated question.  A List is lighter than an ObservableCollection and that was the stated question.  You would use a ObservableCollection to dynamically insert and remove rows which is NOT in the question.